# Stuck on login screen using spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, axios

I'm currently using spring security to authenticate my login screen. It works as expected for invalid logins(faulty username/password combination). When I enter the correct username and password I get the success message but get redirected back to the login screen. I'm using axios on the front end to redirect me to the login screen after receiving a good request. I don't want to upload all the code I'm using but I will upload what I think is necessary to solve the issue.

**SecurityConfiguration.java**

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login", "/signup").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/home/**").authenticated().anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login");
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }
}
```

**javascript code on front end**

```
getRequest(){
                console.log("HERE");
                axios({
                    method: 'post',
                    url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/login',
                    data: {
                        username: this.username,
                        password: this.password
                    }
                })
                .then(res => {
                    alert("Success, Authenticiation processed!");
                    window.location = "http://localhost:8080/home";
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    this.status = "ERROR";
                    console.log("error")
                    
                });
            }
```

Im 100% sure its something to do with the security configuration since I have debugged my controller and nothing seems to be wrong with it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suspect the issue is due to the fact that you bypass the Spring Security login mechanism and build your own using a controller. What you should do is do a post to the regular login endpoint with `FormData` and the username/password. That way Spring Security will handle the login.

Comment: That could work only problem is I want to use my own html code to style the login screen. I have seen it done before I just don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: Have you read my comment? Just post to `/login` instead of `/api/login` and use formdata instead of json. That is the only thing you need to change.